# How to get "No" in if condition when the values is N/A

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using this formula

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'sheet2'!A8:B353,1,FALSE),"Yes","No")
```

But when the VLOOKUP is not finding the value, I've a N/A in my cell with and an error message like did not find value.
How to get a "no" in place of this Error message and N/A value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about the result of the lookup, but just want to know whether the value in cell `A2` appears in `A8:A353`, use one of these patterns:

`=if( iserror( match(A2, 'sheet2'!A8:A353, 0) ), "No", "Yes" )`

`=if( iserror( vlookup(A2, 'sheet2'!A8:A353, 1, false) ), "No", "Yes" )`

If you do want the result from the lookup, but also want to show "(no match)" when there is no match, you can "catch" the error with `ifna()` or `iferror()`, like this:

`=iferror( filter('sheet2'!A8:A353, 'sheet2'!A8:A353 = A2) ), "(no match)" )`

`=ifna( vlookup(A2, 'sheet2'!A8:A353, 1, false), "(no match)" )`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IF use [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)

Relatad

- [Use value from another cell in formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100407/88163)